# Problem with search function in mulipledimensional Array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have an array with City names and postnumbers, that i need to search in, i can search for the city and get the result, but when i search for number it won't find it. so my question is, how do i get my search function to function that way?

my script and Array are like this :

small sampel of array

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9900
        [1] => Town 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9900
        [1] => Town 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9940
        [1] => Town 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9970
        [1] => Town 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9981
        [1] => Town 5
    )
)

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".searchinput").keyup(function(){


var b = document.getElementsByClassName('searchinput')[0].value;

var b = document.getElementById("Searchfield")

var SearchValue=b.value;     
var i=0, k=0, indx=[], msg;
for ( i=0; i<postnummer.length; i++) 
  { for ( k=0; k<postnummer[i].length; k++)   
      { if (postnummer[i][k] === SearchValue){ indx = [i,k]; break; }  
  }    }
if(typeof indx[0] == "undefined" || typeof indx[1] == "undefined"){ 
    msg=("Not found"); }
else { msg="i= "+indx[0]+" k= "+indx[1]; }


var a = document.getElementById("Result");

a.value = b.value + " - " + msg ;

    });
});
```

What happens is when i Type Town 2 i get the following result : Town 2  i= 1 k= 1

so far so good, but i can't get the "0" listing in the array ( the 9900 ) in the result.

and likewise i can't search the array for the 9900 number to get the result back ...

Comment: Please create a snippet of your problem

Comment: As this is a pure JavaScript question, please provide the array sample in JavaScript notation (use `console.log(JSON.stringify(postnummer))`) not PHP.

Comment: `[[9900, 'Town 1'], [9900, 'Town 2'], [9940, 'Town 3'], [9970, 'Town 4'], [9981, 'Town 5']]` is the array (guessing data types)

Comment: You could use `array.filter()` to simplify the code alot if you can use that. Something like `.filter(function( location ){ return location[0] === 9900; });` will already take you a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)(`===`) in your if condition:

```
postnummer[i][k] === SearchValue
```

`b.value` returns a string ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value)). If you type a `9900` in your input, `SearchValue` will be "9900" and not `9900`

Here's a working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".searchinput").keyup(function() {
    var postnummer = [
        [9900, 'Town 1'],
        [9900, 'Town 2'],
        [9940, 'Town 3'],
        [9970, 'Town 4'],
        [9981, 'Town 5']
      ],
      b = document.getElementById("Searchfield"),
      SearchValue = b.value, // this returns a string
      i = 0,
      k = 0,
      indx = [];

      for (i = 0; i < postnummer.length; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < postnummer[i].length; k++) {
          // changed it to ==
          if (postnummer[i][k] == SearchValue) {
            indx = [i, k];
            break;
          }
        }
      }

    if (indx.length > 1)
      console.log(indx)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="searchinput" id="Searchfield" />
```

Comment: Hey Sorry for late reply, this worked Perfectly, and was much simpler then what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since it required to compare the search value to either `String` or `Number`. You may want to attempt to convert it to `Number` and fallback to original string value if conversion fails (i.e. when `parseInt` returns `NaN`):

```
SearchValue = parseInt(SearchValue) || SearchValue;
```

Then just use strict comparison:

```
postnummer[i][k] === SearchValue
```

In this way you will retain the possibility to compare by both numeric and string values.

Answer (score 0):

Just as another solution, you can use `.reduce` on your `postnummer` array to determine the found indexes of the search subject.

This will return two arrays if you enter `9900`. If you do this, you will get the indexes for the first array and the index of `9900` in it. In addition to this, you will also get the index of the second array and the index of where `9900` is located.

See working example below:

```js
const postnumber = [[9900, 'Town 1'],[9900, 'Town 2'],[9940, 'Town 3'], [9970, 'Town 4'], [9981, 'Town 5']],

  search = '9900', /* 9900 (int) also works due to '==' in .reduce (not strictly testing the value) */
  res = postnumber.reduce((acc, [num, town], i) => {
    if (num == search) return [...acc, [i, 0]];
    if (town == search) return [...acc, [i, 1]];
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(res);
```